# Lectura de tabla html con js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

tengo una tabla que se llena con un textbox de información que tiene el formato de excel (los saltos de linea con el charcode 10 y el tab con el charcode 9), esta información se transforma en una tabla para que luego se registre en una base de datos con ayuda de AJAX y Servlet.

Los códigos son los siguientes:

***HTML***

```
<div id="data" class="col-sm-9" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped w3-white" >
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>Campo1</th>
             <th>Campo2</th>
             <th>Campo3</th>
             <th>Campo N</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody  id="table-body">
         </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
```

***JavaScript***

*Creación de la tabla.*

```
    function tnrtable() {
    var Datos = document.getElementById("textbox").value
    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("data");
    var myTable = document.getElementById("table-body");

    Row = Datos.split(String.fromCharCode(10));
    for (i = 0; i < excelRow.length; i++) {               
      Row[i] = Row[i].split(String.fromCharCode(9));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < Row.length - 1; i++) {
        var k = i;
        var row = myTable.insertRow(k);
        //COLUMNAS
        for (j = 0; j < Row[i].length; j++) {
            if (Row[i][j].length !== 0) {
                var cell = row.insertCell(j);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRow[i][j];
            }
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(myTbody);
    document.body.appendChild(myTable);
}
```

*Registro de datos con Ajax*

```
function Registro() {
    var sw = 0;
    alert("1");
    $('#table-body').each(function (i, row) {
        var dataRow = new Array();
        alert("2");
        var $row = $(row);
        $check = $row.find("td");
        alert("Valor i: " + i);
        if (i !== 0) {
            $check.each(function (j, cell) {
                if (j < 9) {
                    dataRow.push(cell.innerHTML);
                    sw = 1;
                }
            });
            alert("Contador: " + sw);

            $.ajax({
                url: "Registro",  //Servlet donde se registra.
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                   json: dataRow
                },
                success: function (dataRow) {
                    alert(":)");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert(":(");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    if (sw === 0) {
        alert("No hay información a enviar");
    }
    else {
        alert("Información guardada");
        document.location.href = "/Registro";
    }
}
```

Realmente no sé si el problema se encuentra en la generación de la tabla porque la función de registro siempre detecta que no hay información en el body aunque si haya datos generados. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo estás loopeando por los `#table-body` del cual entiendo solo vas a tener uno y los datos van a estar en `<tr></tr>` dentro del mismo.

En ese caso deberías hacer

```
 $('#table-body tr').each(function (i, row) {
 ...
 }
```

De esta forma la variable `row`equivale a cada `tr`, ya que en este momento estás obteniendo solo el `#table-body`.

Comment: correcto, pero después hace un `$row.find("td")` y `$check.each(...)`

Comment: Es verdad, pero por como está ahora encontraría todas las celdas de la tabla. 

Habría que ver como está formada la tabla final para dar una respuesta más completa y precisa. Supongo.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Realmente funcionó ya que faltaba la parte del *tr*. Ya hace bien el registro de información así que todo bien.